# Getting Import Error ResQ(pyres) python for a simple code

Tags: python, tornado, resque

```
import tornado
import tornado.ioloop
import tornado.web
import traceback
import urllib
from pyres import ResQ
class Hello():
    queue = "Hello"

    @staticmethod
    def perform(thing):
        print "Hello " 


class renderui(tornado.web.RequestHandler):
    def get(self):
        self.render("frontpage.html")
        ResQ().enqueue(Hello,"WORLD")
application = tornado.web.Application([
        (r"/", renderui),
        ], debug=True)

if __name__ == "__main__":   application.listen(environ.get('PORT',6001))
tornado.ioloop.IOLoop.instance().start()
```

I went through Resq code as well, I am not able to figure out what is wrong. I am a beginner in python trying to implement resque,help in this would be most welcome. For the above code I am getting the below error,here is the traceback:

Traceback (most recent call last):

> File "/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/pyres/worker.py", line 256, in
>   process return job.perform() File
>   "/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/pyres/job.py", line 67, in perform
>   payload_class = self.safe_str_to_class(payload_class_str) File
>   "/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/pyres/**init**.py", line 97, in
>   safe_str_to_class raise ImportError('') ImportError